# Bash arithmetic expansion with for loop

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a loop that uses command line arguments to determine the range over which it operates. As of now I've tried the following:

```
let a=$1
let best=$2 
for ((i=a ; i < best ; i++)); do 
let bwd_g = $((20 - i))
echo $bwd_g 
done
```

when I call ./test.sh the following output is produced:

```
./test.sh: line 9: let: =: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=")
```

I've spent a large amount of time on coming up with different variants of this code but to no avail and have tried googling the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I am not fully sure about your requirement, but to fix your specific error, try wrapping `let` with `"` and it should fly then, like (there shouldn't be any spaces between variable name(s) and `=`):

```
cat script.sh
let a=$1
let best=$2
for ((i=a ; i < best ; i++)); do
let "bwd_g = $((20 - i))"
echo $bwd_g
done
```

You should use `$((.....))` for doing operations in bash, so better use following rather than `let`:

```
cat script.sh
a=$1
best=$2
for ((i=a ; i < best ; i++)); do
bwd_g=$((20 - i))
echo $bwd_g
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue was with blank spaces on line 4. Please check below.

```
let a=$1
let best=$2
for ((i=a ; i < best ; i++)); do
let bwd_g=$((20 - i))
echo $bwd_g 
done
```

and I ran it as

```
bash script.sh 5 10
```